# <ripple> alternative for FloatingActionButton

Tags: android, xml

I am looking for an alternative for `ripple` since it requires a minimum API of **21.**

My aim is to make a `FloatingActionButton` which I successfully completed, and everything works fine for me but the problem is that the app should work in android 4.0 as well and for achieving that, I need to come up with an alternative for `ripple`.

Any suggestions or guidance in this context is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i just found the answer and decided to put it in case anyone came across the same problem

i fixed it with these lines of code

```
ImageView imgv = new ImageView(this);
        imgv.setImageResource(R.drawable.cam);

        FloatingActionButton actionButton = new    
  FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(imgv)
             .build();
```